# How to read answer in JSON format,and transfer them into labels text

Tags: json, vb.net

i need some help. I wanna make a program uses the website to search for data,those text come in JSON format,how do i load those files and write them on labels?
like this > `{"mature":null,"status":"Chill","broadcaster_language":"en","display_name":"MexxHD","game":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive"}}`

Here is the link i use for read this > https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/MexxHD

I was able to get an "answer" from the website,but i dont know how to print them in labels(here is code what i use)

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" & TextBox1.Text), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
```

How do i from this > {"mature":null,"status":"Chill","broadcaster_language":"en"..
Move information in labels like Labe1.text to be Chill and label2.text to be en...

Answer (score 1):

A JSON string is not just a complex string - it is serialized data (a class, dictionary, array etc).  Nor can you ignore the parts you don't care about: your post leaves off a big chunk at the end.

In this case, it looks like it can be deserialized to a Dictionary, with the last element ("_links") itself being a dictionary.  Looking at the text, the first element ("mature") is null, so I use `Dictionary(Of String, Object)`:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

' I downloaded it for ease, you could use the response
Dim json = File.ReadAllText("C:\Temp\MexxHD.json")

Dim col As Dictionary(Of String, Object) 
col = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(json)
```

That's it really.  Display the contents (remember at least one value is `Nothing`):

```
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In col
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, value: {1}", kvp.Key,
                      If(kvp.Value Is Nothing, "Null", kvp.Value.ToString))
Next
```

Output:

> Key: mature, value: Null
>   Key: status, value: Chill
>   Key: broadcaster_language, value: en
>   Key: display_name, value: MexxHD
>   (etc)

The links part can be deserialized to its own dictionary:

```
Dim JLinks = col("_links").ToString
Dim linkCol As Dictionary(Of String, String) 
linkCol = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(JLinks)

Console.WriteLine("********* LINKS ********* ")
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In linkCol
    Console.WriteLine("K: {0} V: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
Next
```

Output:

> ********* LINKS *********
>   K: self V: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/mexxhd
>   K: follows V: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/mexxhd/follows
>   K: commercial V: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/mexxhd/commercial
>   (etc)

When the JSON appears to be an array of class objects, there are online tools which will create the class structure from the JSON string such as [this one which will do VB classes](http://www.httputility.net/json-to-csharp-vb-typescript-class.aspx)

Just fetch the items you want from the Dictionary.  Do keep in mind that some values can be `Nothing` as is the case for "mature" which can lead to a [NullReference Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26761773/1070452):

```
Label1.Text = col("status").ToString()
```

Answer (score -1):

First do this

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
```

Second Add Reference > Newtonsoft.Json.dll

And Third use this code

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
        Dim reader As StreamReader    

    request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("replace with your WEB LINK, HttpWebRequest)
                response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
                reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

                Dim rawresp As String
                rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()
                Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawresp)
                '===============LABELS TEXT===========================
                Label1.Text = jResults(" replace with your token ").ToString()
```

And Last One,Replace with your informations